# accomplishing 'sqlldr' through a stand alone procedure

Tags: oracle, interface

I am new in interface and write now I am gone through some assignment.
I have one question that is :

i am well acquainted with the method of loading the data from .dat file(and .ctl) into staging table using putty(using sqlldr) but i have a requirement to accomplish the same task(i.e loading data from .dat flie into staging table) through some pl/sql procedure . so please suggest the logic.....

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would use [external tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm).  The syntax is going to be very similar to a SQL*Loader control file but it is an object defined in the database that allows you to expose the file as if it were a relational table.  You can then do your load simply by querying the external table.

This does require, though, that the data file is present on the database server's file system.